# Properties of the nucleons and the nucleus from the interactions between quarks and gluons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory, gluons

Is it possible to deduce the properties of the nucleus or that of the nucleons from the QCD interactions between the constituent quarks and gluons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool for calculating QCD processes, [lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD)

> Lattice QCD is a well-established non-perturbative approach to solving the quantum chromodynamics (QCD) theory of quarks and gluons. It is a lattice gauge theory formulated on a grid or lattice of points in space and time. When the size of the lattice is taken infinitely large and its sites infinitesimally close to each other, the continuum QCD is recovered.

If you google "lattice QCD calculation of nucleon" a number of papers with calculations appear.

The property of nuclei are modeled with the [shell nuclear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), or pion exchange models, etc,  because the [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) is a spill over force.

The answer is yes, there are models that can give the properties of both nucleons and nuclei.

Comment: Dear @anna v Can the properties of nucleons be understood from a renormalization group flow of QCD?

Comment: QCD diverges in normal pertubation , because the coupling has the value of 1  that is why they use lattice QCD,